# Which branch of math studies this problem?

Tags: functions, reference-request, algorithms, arithmetic

If we want to calculate the same arithmetic operation on 2 numbers, to say something, the square of $5$ and $7$, we can calculate the square of each one, or we can do this:

$$a= 5*1,000,000+7 = 5,000,007$$
$$a^2=25000070000049$$

Now, ignoring the effort to pack $5$ and $7$ in $a$, and extract $25$ and $49$ from the result, we managed to do the calculations in parallel, with a single calculation. Now I have some questions:

There is a name for this trick? A branch of math?
Where is the practical limit? How many numbers can be calculated in parallel?
What type of functions can benefit from it?

We need in general functions like
$$f(g(x,y))=h(f(x),f(y))$$
where we can unpack $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ from $h(f(x),f(y))$ for all $x$ and $y$ that satisfy certain restrictions

Comment: Abstract the numbers and see how many you can do this trick with.. I imagine you will come across some unwanted terms (like the 7 in the middle) that you will have to know how to remove. Seeing as how it is isolated by zeros, the trick might be in allocating  0 space depending on string length of inputs. This is probably more computationally costly than just doing them separately though (think all the + and * the computer has to make and compare each process). Curious for sure

Comment: @KevinS I suspect/hope that there must be optimal functions f,g,h, where f is computationally expensive, and it allows to parallelly process more than 2 variables at once.

Comment: A more efficient way to process two numbers in parallel is to build two processing units into your hardware and use both processing units simultaneously. This way you are not wasting energy and space on your chip for the circuitry that calculates $2(5\cdot7)$ while you're calculating $5^2$ and $7^2.$

Comment: @David K What if you keep doing calculations, instead of a single square, and you find a way to pack 10 numbers in a 64 bit variable

Comment: A long series of calculations is even better for running in parallel on two processing units. But if you find a way to pack 10 numbers into a 64-bit variable, then you are dealing with very small and/or low-precision numbers (only 6 bits each!) and you may be able to play some tricks with them. I would call this "bit twiddling", but that's a very informal term.

Comment: @David K if you allow the digits to superpose, you may have more than 6 bits per number. Your argument is that there are limitations, but that's the point: what are the limitations? What kind of functions can do this?

Comment: If you allow the digits to superpose, then you have fewer than 6 bits per number that are actually useful, because the superposed digits interfere with each other. There is quite a lot written on the limitations of computing; spend a few years studying the literature and you may know some of it. In particular you could look into parallel computing, which has many ways to approach your problem (ranging from the functions of the processor in your computer right now, to purely theoretical networks, and many things in between).

Comment: @David K if a function is invertible, and assigns an unique value to each pair of values x,y, then x,y are recoverable, no matter the bit representation. We are not necessarily speaking of $x^2$, or the packing shown, -as illustration only-, on the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137380/discussion-between-david-k-and-colim).

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you haven't reduced the number of computations, as you first needed to calculate $5 \times 10^6 + 7$ before squaring it, and must also find a way to extract the squares from the new number. In general, what you've done is nothing more than $$(10^n x + y)^2 = 10^{2n} x^2 + 10^n (2xy) + y^2.$$

In your example, you chose $n = 6, x = 5, y = 7.$ Assuming that $n$ is sufficiently large, you'll be able to  separate the squares by strings of zeroes. More precisely, let's say that $10^{m-1} \le x \le 10^m$ and $10^{k-1} \le y \le 10^k$. Then $2xy \le 2 \times 10^{km}$, and with $n = km + 1$, we have:
\begin{align*}
(10^n x + y)^2 \mod 10^{2k} &= y^2 \\
\lfloor(10^n x + y)^2/10^{2n}\rfloor &= x^2.
\end{align*}

Returning to you example, we have $k = m = 1$, so $n = 3$ and we obtain
\begin{align*}
25070049 \mod 10^{2} &= 49 \\
\lfloor 25.07005\rfloor &= 25.
\end{align*}

More squares can be included in a similar fashion, for example by taking $(10^n x + 10^p y + z)^2$ and finding appropriate bounds. Larger powers should be possible in a similar way as well. That said, I suspected that this algorithm is significantly more costly than squaring the numbers individually.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the unpacking. I used $f_{(X)}=x^2$ as a simple illustrative example, but I expect that there must be functions $f$ more expensive to calculate, relative to the packing cost, where more than 2 variables can be packed, and the packing may overlap the digits. Also, $2xy$ is an extra calculation that may be useful. Maybe there is a way to bundle multiple functions in a single calculation.

Answer (score 0):

The name for this would be the analysis of algorithms, with particular reference to parallel algorithms. It would usually be regarded as a field somewhere between pure mathematics and computer science.

Algorithms for arithmetical operations are discussed extensively in the works of Donald Knuth.